# Can not find new elements after javascript append using chrome webdriver

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, xunit.net

Here's the simple HTML generated from a c# dotnet core asp pages, application.  I'm trying to get the number of input boxes from colorList div using a webdriver test.  The initial count of two  works, but once i simulate the clicking the button labeled "+" i still only get two, where i expected to get three.  I've tried all kinds of different waits both implicit and explicit, but can't seem to get it to work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Home page - SeleniumWebTest</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container body-content">
        <body>
        <form method="post" id="Form" action="/?handler=saveall">
            <div><h4>Colors</h4><button type="button" onclick="CreateColor();" value="create" class="btn-sm">+</button></div>
            <div class="indent" id="colorlist">
                    <input value="Red" type="text" id="Colors" name="Colors" /><br />
                    <input value="Blue" type="text" id="Colors" name="Colors" /><br />
            </div>
            <br />
            <div>
                <h1>More Stuff</h1>
            </div>
            <br />
            <button type="submit" value="SaveAll" class="btn btn-primary">Save All</button>
        <input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="CfDJ8Ps9gVily6NMr7L9g0lJf0cQzaqUzEq26TUrHCT4rH1GQIY0QLmjjc6cnQBE8aBvQlWdXAQZ2ub08pm2yIMWkUICO51XkWH6d11pf7y3pr3HwqRgBkiFdpaHSFYQsJsWdLba01RGCL8yYsUad9Vn2JQ" /></form>
</body>


<script type="text/javascript">
    function CreateColor() {

        var form = document.getElementById("colorlist");
        var input = document.createElement("input");
        input.type = "text";
        input.id = "ColorId";
        input.name = "ColorName";
        form.appendChild(input);
        linebreak = document.createElement("br");
        form.appendChild(linebreak);
    };
</script>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's my test

```
        [Fact]
        public void ColorTest()
        {
            var _driver = new ChromeDriver();

            _driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://localhost:44394/");
            Assert.Equal("Home page - SeleniumWebTest", _driver.Title);

            var colorInputs = _driver.FindElements(By.Id("Colors"));
            Assert.Equal(2, colorInputs.Count);

            var plusButton = _driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[text()='+']"));
            plusButton.Click();

            var colorInputs2 = _driver.FindElements(By.Id("Colors"));
            Assert.Equal(colorInputs.Count+1,colorInputs2.Count); // <-- Fails

            _driver.Close();
            _driver.Quit();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yikes, after creating the question i see the problem.  The id's for the new elements were being generated differently for razor pages versus javascript.